# Cannot access ec2 Free tier instance from SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a EC2 instance(t2.micro) but after lunching the instance there is no remote SSH access.

- I created VPC and subnet
- Public IPv4 address is assigned.
- I created key pair and use it with putty

[image]

- Network configuration
  [image]

But when I create the instance there is no SSH access from my PC. I get connection timeout.

Also when I try to connect using connect feature I get: `Failed to connect to your instance EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see Set up EC2 Instance Connect at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html.`

Can you advise how I can fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Could you show how are you using the keypair you created to access the server? Is this server publicly accessable(the subnet has route(0.0.0.0/0) to internet gateway?

Comment: yes the server should be public. Can you show me how to configure the subnet to route(0.0.0.0/0) to internet gateway

Comment: Your subnet's route table should have various routes, one of them must be 0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW*. You can find this route table by clicking on the subnet in which your instance resides.  Also turn off any vpn/proxy you are using. Also create another security group with ssh access to yourself and attach to the instance and remove the default one(launch wizard..).

Comment: See [How do I troubleshoot Amazon EC2 instance connection timeout errors from the internet?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-vpc-troubleshoot/) Start with security groups.